# A bounded measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Let $g:R→R$ be a non-negative integrable function. Let $f:R→R$ be a bounded measurable function satisfying $f(x)>1$ for every $x∈R$. Suppose that $∫_R f^n g≤M$ for every $n∈N$. Show that $g(x)=0$ for almost all $x∈R$.

I think can use the next theorem:

Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on a set of finite measure $E$. Suppose ${f_n}$ is uniformly pointwise bounded on E,that is, there is a number $M≥0$ for which $|f_n|≤M$ for all $n$. If ${f_n}→f$ pointwise on E, then $lim_{n→∞} ∫_E f_n=∫_E f$.

Comment: Hint: suppose $g > \epsilon$ on a set $E$ of positive but finite measure. Then $\epsilon\int_E f^n \leq M$, what can you conclude from this? As a further hint, try finding a positive measure subset of $E$ such that $f\geq c > 1$ on $E$ and take limits.